# trigonometry question (high school level)

Tags: trigonometry

Why does $\cos(50+60) = \cos(115)$?

I understand that $\cos(x+y) = \cos(x)\cos(y) - \sin(x)\sin(y)$,

but I dont understand how to apply this formula in this question or if I use another method to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: it doesn't. ()()

Comment: Perhaps we should assume the question was intended to read "Why does $\cos(50+60) = \cos(110)$?  In this case, I don't think you even need the angle addition formula, even though you could use it...

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't.  Quite simply put, $\cos(50 + 60) \ne \cos(115)$ (arguments in degrees).  You're running into difficulty because you're trying to prove something that isn't correct.